# Removing Oxbox GripTip

Tags: plumbing, drainage, washer

[image]

Hey guys! I'm trying to install a drainage line and I came across this Oxbox drainage line cover. I couldn't figure out how to remove it and have been attacking it with pliers to no success.

Does anyone know exactly what's supposed to happen here? Does the whole bottom disk come out or just that little nub?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just went through the same problem, but you do NOT need to cut the knockout with .  Just grab the nub with a set of pliers and lift/pry.  The knockout peals out really easily this way.[image]

Answer (score 1):

"[Drain knockout is easy to remove with pliers](http://www.siouxchief.com/products/supply/access/laundry-boxes/oxbox-washing-machine-outlet-box-with-minirester-water-hammer-arresters)" –siouxchief.com

No they're not. You need to use a utility knife. This should have been done before it was installed. I'm unfamiliar with that type, because it looks like it has a stub that you can cut open, shove the hose over it, and use a hose clamp. (?)

Usually you just **cut it out, tracing the inside of the circle**, and shove the hose down in there. You're sure there's a (2") drain pipe connected to it inside the wall, right? DO NOT over cut the circle or you'll ruin the box. Start small if you're unsure. Be careful; don't cut yourself.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use a utility blade to cut through the molding line from below, then when you’ve cut about half of the circle, you can pry the rest of it out without breaking.

Absolutely preposterous that this part ships this way.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me: I scored around the rim with a small hex wrench, then used a vise-group to pull the nipple upward. It took a little force to remove the cover. Your advice helped a lot. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I used a util blade to gouge hole.